# Milestone overview in GITLAB

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, milestone

I know how to manage milestones for several projects, but is there also an option (or a plugin) where I can see all (open) milestones from all projects?

edit: I use Gitlab

Comment: At the moment there is no way to view all milestones in standard Gitlab installation.

Comment: You want to see it in GitLab GUI, or somewhere else ? If you don't need to see it inside Gitlab GUI, you can use API: retrive all projects id (`GET /projects/all` with admin token in parameter) and then for each project id, retrive his milestones (`GET /projects/:id/milestones`). You will have all milestones of all projects, but not *inside* GitLab.

Comment: thanks @metaDiego but I needed to see them inside the Gitlab GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitlab 7.1 includes a new feature: Group Milestones.

Users are now able to see all milestones for different projects in the same group.
It is not exactly what you wanted to do, but is a viable alternative, I think.

Reference: https://about.gitlab.com/2014/07/22/gitlab-7-dot-1-released/

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @novalore didn't fully meet my needs, in the meantime however this is what works for me:

in Gitlab under Dashboard -> Issues select "Everyones's" - that way at least all/open/closed issues of all projects are visible

Answer (score 1):

> is there also an option (or a plugin) where I can see all (open) milestones from all projects?

4 years later, you could consider the latest GitLab 11.2 released yesterday (August 22nd, 2018)

See "[Group milestones on dashboard milestones list page](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#group-milestones-on-dashboard-milestones-list-page) "

> Milestones in GitLab are useful for tracking work within an iteration or a sprint. In particular, group-level milestones allow issues across several different projects to be tracked together.
>
> With this release, we are showing group milestones on the dashboard milestones page.
> **This means that users will now be able to see all milestones (both project and group milestones) that they have access to in the GitLab instance, all in a single location.**

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_2/group-milestones-dashboard.png]

- [See issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/35748).
- [See documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/milestones/).